# how to take some spesific string form sparql

Tags: php, sparql

I have this code :

```
$querystring = '
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2016/karya_ilmiah#>
SELECT ?judulNaskah ?linkNaskah
WHERE { ?naskah :judulNaskah ?judulNaskah. filter regex(str(?judulNaskah),"Sistem Informasi Manajemen"). 
?naskah :linkNaskah ?linkNaskah} ORDER BY ?judulNaskah';
$result=$model->sparqlQuery($querystring,"HTML");
echo $result;
```

and I got this output:
[image]

How can I get just spesific string from output above, 
thank you for your help
best regard

Comment: use regex to extract your desired text, or if the output is a simple html use HTMLDOM instead

Comment: My script has output like = Pengembangan Sistem Informasi Manajemen Data Sekolah Pada Dinas Pendidikan Kabupaten Ogan Komering Ulu
  rdf:type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
all I need to do with my code is to remove rdf extension

Comment: remove this `rdf:type=w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string` ?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Since you requested HTML, you can simply modifiy the HTML dom tree and replace the string.

Comment: go with [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) or if it's more complicated string you may go with : [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: ok thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) function to get the lexical form of an RDF literal:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2016/karya_ilmiah#>
SELECT  (str(?judulNaskahLit) AS ?judulNaskah) (str(?linkNaskahLit) AS ?linkNaskah)
WHERE {
  ?naskah  :judulNaskah  ?judulNaskahLit
  FILTER regex(str(?judulNaskahLit), "Sistem Informasi Manajemen")
  ?naskah  :linkNaskah  ?linkNaskahLit
}
ORDER BY ?judulNaskah
```

Comment: your script can running well, but the rdf datatype still appears. How can i remove that datatype rdf. Thank you.

Comment: That can't be, if so it's not following SPARQL standards! Can you show some sample data? Which triple store do you use?

Comment: @AKSW, I suppose this is RAP  -  RDF API for PHP misbehaviour.

Comment: my output sparql of judulNaskah is : "Perancangan Aplikasi Fuzzy Multi Criteria Decision Making (FMCDM) Untuk Menentukan Nilai Ketidakpastian Sistem Pakar
  rdf:type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string".  I want to remove : " rdf:type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" So my output just= "Perancangan Aplikasi Fuzzy Multi Criteria Decision Making (FMCDM) Untuk Menentukan Nilai Ketidakpastian Sistem Pakar ".

Comment: I understand, but it looks like the library that you use doesn't do what the SPARQL query I've shown is supposed to do. Thus, you have to edit the HTML that you get back.